# quick RPM database test for changes

Tags: rpm, berkeley-db

I'm looking at an RPM database.  It is composed of the usual set of db4 files;

Basenames Dirnames Filedigests Group Installtid Name Packages Providename Provideversion Pubkeys Requirename Requireversion Sha1header Sigmd5 Triggername

I am looking for a quick way to mark the current state of the db; I would like to come back at an arbitrary later time and know if any system-changing rpm transactions have occurred.

For example; perhaps any/all system-modifying transactions would include a change to the 'Packages' file.  If so, I could simply use an md5sum of that file as my 'mark';

[root@host] rpm # cat Packages |md5sum
7c23740eec936870c0ad16f8190a0088  -

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on what you are trying to accomplish, particularly
if attempting snapshots or rollbacks. You seem to want only detection
of changed state.

The secondary indexes are regenerated from Packages with --rebuilddb.

A digest of Packages will also change with --rebuilddb.

You are likely better off examining/saving
    rpm -qa --last
output and perhaps using a digest like
    rpm -qa --last | md5sum
if you wish the digest to be invariant to --rebuilddb events.